# what is the difference between using shift-f5 or the red-X on the controlbox for terminating a debug session?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, debugging

is there a difference in the dispose() functions being called ?

Comment: More specifics would help here - are you talking about closing the debuggee with the X, or visual studio? Which dispose() functions are you wondering about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll guess that you're asking about closing the debuggee via the X button in the top right, versus stopping debugging via the Stop Debugging command (Shift+F5) from Visual Studio.

When you close the app with the X button, any cleanup code you've written for the application will run as normal, including Dispose functions(). On the other hand, stopping with Shift+F5 terminates the process immediately, as though you had terminated it from the Processes tab in Task Manager. This means that no cleanup code will run - the application will have no idea that it is shutting down.